# Primes congruent to $5$ and $7$ modulo $8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p \equiv 5$ or $7$ ($\mathrm{mod}$ $8$) be a prime and let $a$, $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ be such that $p$ | $a^2 + 2b^2$.

Show that $p$ | $a$ and $p$ | $b$.

Clearly, if $p$ divides any of them, then $p$ divides the other, but I don't really see how $p$ must divide one of them.

Comment: What do you mean by $p\equiv 5,7\pmod 8$? Is $p$ equivalent to 5 or 7? It certainly isn't equivalent to 5 and 7.

Comment: p is congruent to one of them

Comment: if $p\equiv5$ or $7\pmod8$, then $-2$ is not a quadratic residue $\pmod p$

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $p\nmid b$. Then we can multiply $a^2+2b^2\equiv0\mod p$ with $b^{-2}$ and get $(ab^{-1})^2+2\equiv0$. Now look at your previous question...

Answer (score 2):

If $p\equiv5$ or $7\pmod8$, then $-2$ is [not a quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#q_=_%C2%B12_and_the_second_supplement) $\pmod p$,

so $a^2+2b^2\equiv0\pmod p$ and $p\nmid b$, which imply $(ab^{-1})^2\equiv-2\pmod p$,

would be a contradiction.